# Curl in PowerShell with custom cookie file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, curl

The following `curl` command works fine in cmd:

```
curl -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d "{\"accountId\":\"123456789\",\"partition\":\"abc\",\"duration\":1234}" https://testabc.com
```

When I try to run the same from PowerShell, I get the  *`-c` is ambiguous* error. I tried replacing `-c` with `SessionVariable`, but then I start getting the following error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Missing an argument for parameter
> 'SessionVariable'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try
> again.

Comment: So you would like everyone to guess on the powershell code you used?

Comment: I used the same script in powershell

Comment: PowerShell converted it to Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: Yep.  Curl is an alias of Invoke-WebRequest.  So you use curl.exe.

Comment: Shouldn't it work as it is in PowerShell then? Do I need to make any modifications?

Comment: If you are that incessant on using `curl` without changing it to `curl.exe` then you can use the `remove-alias` command before the `curl` command so that the alias does not exist for the current session.

Comment: Thank you! I tried removing the alias with `Remove-Item alias:curl`. I do see that all the errors are gone now, but the response (`{"Message":null}`) is null. When I run the same command in cmd, I do get a response.

Comment: Maybe you have more than one curl command on your computer and the PATH in CMD is different than where powershell finds it?

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions to execute the correct curl binary:

- Run `curl.exe` instead of `curl`. This is similar to why `where` works in cmd but in PowerShell you must run `where.exe` because `where` is an alias to `Where-Object`
- Remove the `curl` alias by running `Remove-Alias curl`. You can put this in the [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1) to remove it by default
- Install PowerShell Core and use it instead

That's because in the past `curl` was an alias of [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) along with `wget`

```
PS C:\> Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
Alias           iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest
Alias           wget -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

When [MS added tar.exe and curl.exe to Windows 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/) that causes some confusion since now running `curl` will invoke the alias instead of the executable (that's easy to understand since an alias will have higher priority just like in bash). In PowerShell core (i.e. version 6.0+) those aliases have been removed. See [remove curl and wget aliases](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/1901)

```
PS C:\> Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

---

**Update:**

You must also **modify your quotes** because PowerShell has different [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1) which is more similar to bash and is more standardized and much better than the messy one in cmd:

```powershell
curl -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d '{"accountId":"123456789","partition":"abc","duration":1234}' https://testabc.com
```

---

**Update 2:**

I tried capturing the command line passed to `curl.exe` with [sysmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) and in cmd it's like this

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\curl.exe" -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d "{\"accountId\":\"123456789\",\"partition\":\"abc\",\"duration\":1234}" https://testabc.com
```

while in PowerShell it's like this

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\curl.exe" -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d {"accountId":"123456789","partition":"abc","duration":1234} https://testabc.com
```

Notice the difference in the json string. So it seems that **`curl.exe` splits arguments itself and expects the raw `\` escape characters** in the parameters to tokenize the arguments properly. To do that you can wrap the whole json string into `'single quotes'` like this

```powershell
curl -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d '"{\"accountId\":\"123456789\",\"partition\":\"abc\",\"duration\":1234}"' https://testabc.com
```

or just pass [verbatim arguments](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) by adding the [stop-parsing symbol `--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1) after `curl.exe` to force PowerShell to not use its parsing rules and pass the whole string to the executable

```powershell
curl.exe --% -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d "{\"accountId\":\"123456789\",\"partition\":\"abc\",\"duration\":1234}" https://testabc.com
```

Comment: I installed PowerShell core and tried `Remove-Alias curl`. I got this error: `Remove-Alias: This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'curl' does not exist.` This is expected as per your comments. Then I tried executed the same my original curl command with curl.exe and got null again.

Comment: @PKJ you must also change the command because backslash isn't an escape character in powershell. See my edit

Comment: I just tried with your suggestion and its still giving me null. `curl.exe -L -c ./cookie -b ./cookie -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -s -d '{"accountId":"123456789","part":"test","duration":1234}' https://testabc.com/abc`

Comment: @PKJ see my latest update. You need to pass the backslashes to curl.exe