# How to escape space in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, escaping

I run this command in PowerShell

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Typora\Typora.exe' -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello world.md'
```

But Typora says

> C:\User\Administrator\world.md does not exist

It looks like PowerShell executes

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Typora\Typora.exe' 
     -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello' 'world.md'
```

I want to escape the space but the single-quoted not working...

PowerShell version: 5.1.19041.610

Comment: You may try inner double quotes inside the single quotes `-ArgumentList '"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello world.md"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell may not quote strings properly when calling external executables. See

- [Curl in PowerShell with custom cookie file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67051734/995714)
- [PowerShell or CMD errors on space in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472153/995714)

So to fix this you need to pass the literal `"` to the exe file by escaping it properly

```powershell
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Typora\Typora.exe' `
    -ArgumentList '"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello world.md"'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding ` to excape spaces in powershell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Typora\Typora.exe' -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hello`world.md'
```